# fetch POST request throws 401 exception with a valid api key

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have been trying to make POST request to an api with api key authentication. API key I am using is activated and working. API is working fine, it's been tested by backend devs. There's no issue with that. With the valid key, I have been getting 401. There's no other authorisation has been used like bearer token etc. My header options get removed when the request is made, I think thats why authentication fails. without authentication enabled my request works fine.

```js
const formData = new FormData(thisForm).entries();
fetch('api url', { 
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: { 
                    'x-api-key': 'API_KEY'
                },
              body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
            }).then(response => {
            return response.text()
            })
            .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"My header options get removed when the request is made"_ - is that an assumption, or have you _verified_ this to be the case? (If so, how.)

Comment: I have verified it myself also with the backend dev

Comment: regardless of the missing header, the fact that you have `mode: 'no-cors'` and expect `response.text()` to work suggests you don't know what `mode: 'no-cors'` actually does

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your reply, is that the problem? I was getting CORS error so I used 'no-cors' mode. It works fine with authorisation disabled

Comment: mode no-cors ... *Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and **the headers from being anything other than simple headers*** - which is why your header is being dropped

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options: _"Note that `mode: "no-cors"` only allows a limited set of headers in the request: [...]"_ - your `x-api-key` header is absolutely not on that list.

Comment: The proper way of fixing cors errors is to add the respective cors headers to the response.

Comment: @Vinita depends on what CORS error exactly you get. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS